Find Max Date among rows grouped on 3 Columns after transposing (rows to columns)
I have a challenge to limit a data run on last 90 days, but take into account that there may be differing data entry dates for a grouped set of IDs. If I just run the query to limit data to last 90 days, it will not always pull in all the grouped data (of sets of 5). For the most part, the data entry will all be done on same day. However, there are times we don't have the values, so data is entered next day or up to weeks later. I am trying to solve that if any of the 5 activities has an entry date within 90 days to grab the companion grouped data that may be older than 90 so it shows up in the report.
I have this raw table (note, I have to derive the columns from the activity codes).



ProjectID
ActivityCode
ActivityDescription
ActivityResults
DTTM




123456
15
CustomerID
999
4/24/24 18:01


123456
16
InvoiceNo
11232
4/24/24 18:01


123456
1745
CategoryColor
Green
4/25/24 9:01


123456
2256
Size
Large
4/25/24 9:21


123456
4748
Quantity
7
4/25/24 10:05


778899
15
CustomerID
999
3/25/24 17:01


778899
16
InvoiceNo
11233
3/25/24 17:01


778899
1745
CategoryColor
Mauve
3/22/24 7:01


778899
2256
Size
Medium
3/22/24 7:21


778899
4748
Quantity
72
3/23/24 11:05


778899
15
CustomerID
999
3/26/24 14:11


778899
16
InvoiceNo
11240
3/26/24 14:11


778899
1745
CategoryColor
Gold
3/26/24 14:11


778899
2256
Size
X-Small
3/27/24 8:33


778899
4748
Quantity
5
3/26/24 14:11


654321
15
CustomerID
1745
4/26/24 11:15


654321
16
InvoiceNo
19121
4/26/24 11:15


654321
1745
CategoryColor
Blue
4/26/24 11:15


654321
2256
Size
Medium
4/26/24 11:15


654321
4748
Quantity
10
4/26/24 11:15


171718
15
CustomerID
149
4/20/24 13:25


171718
16
InvoiceNo
12001
4/20/24 13:25


171718
1745
CategoryColor
Yellow
4/22/24 12:05


171718
2256
Size
Small
4/22/24 12:05


171718
4748
Quantity
3
4/22/24 12:05


1020212
15
CustomerID
1745
2/27/24 12:15


1020212
16
InvoiceNo
19122
2/27/24 12:15


1020212
1745
CategoryColor
Navy
2/29/24 13:25


1020212
2256
Size
Small
2/25/24 11:35


1020212
4748
Quantity
1
2/25/24 11:35


54443424
15
CustomerID
149
4/11/24 12:45


54443424
16
InvoiceNo
12002
4/11/24 12:55


54443424
1745
CategoryColor
Orange
4/11/24 13:10


54443424
2256
Size
Large
4/11/24 14:18


54443424
4748
Quantity
13
4/11/24 17:13


877767
15
CustomerID
256
1/19/24 11:12


877767
16
InvoiceNo
954679
1/19/24 11:12


877767
1745
CategoryColor
Brown
1/19/24 11:12


877767
2256
Size
3XXL
1/19/24 11:12


877767
4748
Quantity
11
2/7/24  9:10


13233343
15
CustomerID
13
12/15/23 10:11


13233343
16
InvoiceNo
87988
12/14/23 8:24


13233343
1745
CategoryColor
White
2/2/24 7:13


13233343
2256
Size
Exta-Large
12/10/23 6:12


13233343
4748
Quantity
2
12/5/23 16:16


5959598
15
CustomerID
256
1/20/24 13:25


5959598
16
InvoiceNo
954678
1/20/24 13:25


5959598
1745
CategoryColor
Black
1/28/24 12:05


5959598
2256
Size
Exta-Large
1/29/24 12:05


5959598
4748
Quantity
34
1/31/24 12:05


434342
15
CustomerID
13
12/20/23 13:25


434342
16
InvoiceNo
87987
12/20/23 13:25


434342
1745
CategoryColor
Pink
12/28/23 12:05


434342
2256
Size
Exta-Small
12/29/23 12:05


434342
4748
Quantity
29
12/31/23 12:05



The results I am trying to get is this:



ProjectID
CustomerID
InvoiceNo
CategoryColor
Size
Quantity
DTTM




123456
999
11232
Green
Large
7
4/25/24 10:05


171718
149
12001
Yellow
Small
3
4/22/24 12:05


654321
1745
19121
Blue
Medium
10
4/26/24 11:15


778899
999
11233
Mauve
Medium
72
3/25/24 17:01


778899
999
11240
Gold
X-Small
5
3/27/24 08:33


877767
256
954679
Brown
3XXL
11
2/7/24 9:10


1020212
1745
19122
Navy
Small
1
2/29/24 13:25


5959598
256
954678
Black
Exta-Large
34
1/31/24 12:05


13233343
13
87988
White
Exta-Large
2
2/2/2024 7:13


54443424
149
12002
Orange
Large
13
4/11/24 17:13



Here is my code:
CREATE TABLE Customer ( 
  ProjectID INT
  , ActivityCode VARCHAR(10)
  , ActivityDescription VARCHAR(25)
  , ActivityResults VARCHAR (25)
  , DTTM DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO Customer(ProjectID, ActivityCode, ActivityDescription, ActivityResults, DTTM)
VALUES 
('778899', '15', 'CustomerID', '999', '3/25/24 17:01'),
('778899', '16', 'InvoiceNo', '11233', '3/25/24 17:01'),
('778899', '1745', 'CategoryColor', 'Mauve', '3/22/2024 07:01'),
('778899', '2256', 'Size', 'Medium', '3/22/2024 07:21'),
('778899', '4748', 'Quantity', '72', '3/23/2024 11:05'),

('778899', '15', 'CustomerID', '999', '3/26/24 14:11'),
('778899', '16', 'InvoiceNo', '11240', '3/26/24 14:11'),
('778899', '1745', 'CategoryColor', 'Gold', '3/26/2024 14:11'),
('778899', '2256', 'Size', 'X-Small', '3/27/2024 08:33'),
('778899', '4748', 'Quantity', '5', '3/26/2024 14:11'),

('1020212', '15', 'CustomerID', '1745', '2/27/2024 12:15'),
('1020212', '16', 'InvoiceNo', '19122', '2/27/2024 12:15'),
('1020212', '1745', 'CategoryColor', 'Navy', '2/29/2024 13:25'),
('1020212', '2256', 'Size', 'Small', '2/25/2024 11:35'),
('1020212', '4748', 'Quantity', '1', '2/25/2024 11:35'),

('54443424', '15', 'CustomerID', '149', '4/11/2024 12:45'),
('54443424', '16', 'InvoiceNo', '12002', '4/11/2024 12:55'),
('54443424', '1745', 'CategoryColor', 'Orange', '4/11/2024 13:10'),
('54443424', '2256', 'Size', 'Large', '4/11/2024 14:18'),
('54443424', '4748', 'Quantity', '13', '4/11/2024 17:13'),

('877767', '15', 'CustomerID', '256', '1/19/2024 11:12'),
('877767', '16', 'InvoiceNo', '954679', '1/19/2024 11:12'),
('877767', '1745', 'CategoryColor', 'Brown', '1/19/2024 11:12'),
('877767', '2256', 'Size', '3XXL', '1/19/2024 11:12'),
('877767', '4748', 'Quantity', '11', '2/7/2024 9:10'),

('13233343', '15', 'CustomerID', '13', '12/15/2023 10:11'),
('13233343', '16', 'InvoiceNo', '87988', '12/14/2023 8:24'),
('13233343', '1745', 'CategoryColor', 'White', '2/2/2024 7:13'),
('13233343', '2256', 'Size', 'Exta-Large', '12/10/2023 6:12'),
('13233343', '4748', 'Quantity', '2', '12/5/2023 16:16'),

('123456', '15', 'CustomerID', '999', '4/24/24 18:01'),
('123456', '16', 'InvoiceNo', '11232', '4/24/24 18:01'),
('123456', '1745', 'CategoryColor', 'Green', '4/25/2024 09:01'),
('123456', '2256', 'Size', 'Large', '4/25/2024 09:21'),
('123456', '4748', 'Quantity', '7', '4/25/2024 10:05'),

('654321', '15', 'CustomerID', '1745', '4/26/2024 11:15'),
('654321', '16', 'InvoiceNo', '19121', '4/26/2024 11:15'),
('654321', '1745', 'CategoryColor', 'Blue', '4/26/2024 11:15'),
('654321', '2256', 'Size', 'Medium', '4/26/2024 11:15'),
('654321', '4748', 'Quantity', '10', '4/26/2024 11:15'),

('171718', '15', 'CustomerID', '149', '4/20/2024 13:25'),
('171718', '16', 'InvoiceNo', '12001', '4/20/2024 13:25'),
('171718', '1745', 'CategoryColor', 'Yellow', '4/22/2024 12:05'),
('171718', '2256', 'Size', 'Small', '4/22/2024 12:05'),
('171718', '4748', 'Quantity', '3', '4/22/2024 12:05'),

('5959598', '15', 'CustomerID', '256', '1/20/2024 13:25'),
('5959598', '16', 'InvoiceNo', '954678', '1/20/2024 13:25'),
('5959598', '1745', 'CategoryColor', 'Black', '1/28/2024 12:05'),
('5959598', '2256', 'Size', 'Exta-Large', '1/29/2024 12:05'),
('5959598', '4748', 'Quantity', '34', '1/31/2024 12:05'),

('434342', '15', 'CustomerID', '13', '12/20/2023 13:25'),
('434342', '16', 'InvoiceNo', '87987', '12/20/2023 13:25'),
('434342', '1745', 'CategoryColor', 'Pink', '12/28/2023 12:05'),
('434342', '2256', 'Size', 'Exta-Small', '12/29/2023 12:05'),
('434342', '4748', 'Quantity', '29', '12/31/2023 12:05');


-- QUERY database
--SELECT * FROM Customer;
SELECT 
 main.ProjectID
,custid.ActivityResults CustomerID
,invno.ActivityResults InvoiceNo
,color.ActivityResults CategoryColor
,size.ActivityResults Size
,qty.ActivityResults Quantity
,DTTM

FROM (SELECT
 ProjectID
,ActivityCode
,ActivityDescription
,ActivityResults
,DTTM

From Customer
WHERE ActivityCode IN (15,16,1745,2256,4748)) main

LEFT JOIN (SELECT
 ProjectID
,ActivityCode
,ActivityDescription
,ActivityResults
FROM Customer
WHERE ActivityCode = 15) custid ON main.ProjectID = custid.ProjectID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT
 ProjectID
,ActivityCode
,ActivityDescription
,ActivityResults
FROM Customer
WHERE ActivityCode = 16) invno ON main.ProjectID = invno.ProjectID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT
 ProjectID
,ActivityCode
,ActivityDescription
,ActivityResults
FROM Customer
WHERE ActivityCode = 1745) color ON main.ProjectID = color.ProjectID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT
 ProjectID
,ActivityCode
,ActivityDescription
,ActivityResults
FROM Customer
WHERE ActivityCode = 2256) size ON main.ProjectID = size.ProjectID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT
 ProjectID
,ActivityCode
,ActivityDescription
,ActivityResults
FROM Customer
WHERE ActivityCode = 4748) qty ON main.ProjectID = qty.ProjectID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT
 ProjectID
,ActivityCode
,ActivityDescription
,ActivityResults
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID, CASE WHEN ActivityCode = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, CASE WHEN ActivityCode = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY DTTM DESC) RN
FROM Customer
) MaxDTTM ON main.ProjectID = MaxDTTM.ProjectID
WHERE RN = 1

Thank you for any suggestions

Firstly, your sample data isn't complete. You need to cover all possible cases e.g.

All 5 values older than 90 days
Some of the 5 values older then 90 days
Some of the 5 values exactly 90 days old i.e. the exact last date that should be included
None of the values older than 90 days

As for the solution, first we use a window function to find the most recent of the 5 entries per project and use that across the entire project.
Then we use conditional aggregation to convert the 5 rows to columns.
Finally we filter by age less than 90 days.
with cte1 as (
  select *
    , min(datediff(day,DTTM,getdate())) over (partition by ProjectId) Age
  from Customer
)
select
  ProjectId
  , max(case when ActivityCode = 15 then ActivityResults else null end) CustomerId
  , max(case when ActivityCode = 16 then ActivityResults else null end) InvoiceNo
  , max(case when ActivityCode = 1745 then ActivityResults else null end) CategoryColor
  , max(case when ActivityCode = 2256 then ActivityResults else null end) [Size]
  , max(case when ActivityCode = 4748 then ActivityResults else null end) Quantity
  , max(DTTM) DTTM
from cte1
where Age < 90
group by ProjectId;

Note: you need to double check that the combination of datediff and < 90 gives the desired result as its easy to be a day out with this logic and you don't provide sample data to test against.
DBFiddle

I think you might need to keep on the relevant activity codes in the top-level cte.

@Dale, it's not clear to me that those are the only possible activity codes. If there are others then potentially one of them could be roped into the 90-day cutoff even though the specific five of interest were not.
